# jstree in complex environment & coffee not showing any icons nor outline

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, jstree

I included (jquery) jsTree in my already complex environmemt, and using coffee script, I got a fast 'it works' but now i stuck with no images showing nor getting any outline of the tree displayed

Although I think my prob is behind CSS I tell:

I want to populate jstree progrmmaticaly so i made made this approach

```
open =>
        @$container=dlg.$form.find('#tree_container')
        @$container.jstree(
            core:
                animation: 2000 #WORKS!
#               check_callback: true
#               plugins: [ "checkbox", "dnd", "massload", "search", "sort", "state", "types", "unique", "wholerow" ]
                themes:
                    stripes: true
                    icons: true
                    dots: true
                expand_selected_onload: true

                data: (node,cb) =>
                    @fill_node(node,cb)
        )
fill_node:(node,cb) =>
    say node
    if node.id=='#'
        cb([
                id: 'menu'
                text: 'menu2'
                type: 'menu'
                children: true
            ,
                id:'page'
                text: 'page1'
                children: true
                icon: '/assets/gif/16/document.png'
            ])
    else
        say 'next node:',node
        cb(id: node.id+"c", text:node.id+"c")
```

that works in principle, but I only get "DIVS" one after the other, no outline, no icons;

I can open and close with click but nothing else

`icon: '/assets/gif/16/document.png'`  for example is loaded as my browser tells me, but not shown

If I take a look at bowsers Styles (debug) I cant find any thing where to hook on and go further

I got stuck, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include the CSS theme on your page? It is listed as 2) here:
http://www.jstree.com/ (Overview tab)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/themes/default/style.min.css" />
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/themes/default-dark/style.min.css" />
```

**EDIT**: Based on the comments - if you want to use the dark theme, you need to both include the CSS **and configure your tree accordingly**, which I do not see in your code:
http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=themes&f=$.jstree.defaults.core.themes.name

```
// something like this
themes:
   name : 'default-dark'
```

Comment: style is included and in use, as I can see in browser panel

Comment: Edited my answer based on new info - if you include a theme different from the default one, you need to also configure your instance accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem persist with the `default-dark` theme, if I switch to `default`, it works like a charm

I will accept my answer as soon as I know why.

Comment: I edited my original answer after you clarified that you are including the dark CSS theme, but not configuring the instance to use the dark theme. If this is what you did of course - please let me know which CSS file you included.